# How to save to Media folder via Mediastore in CameraX?

Tags: android, mediastore, android-camerax

I am still new to android programming. I am trying to take a photo using CameraX API. However, the sample code at [Google Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#0) only saves the photo on the app's private directory in compliance with [Android's Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage). I am not still knowledgeable with Mediastore so can you please lead me to a documentation on how to integrate Mediastore to CameraX?

Comment: Please post the used code now for saving your picture. If the code indeed saves to apps private directory then it should cintinue to work on Android 10 and 11. So why do you wanna use the MediaStore?

Comment: @blackapps The code I am using is similar to the one in https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#0. I would like to use MediaStore to save photos in Picture, or atleast in the DCIM directory. Also, getExternalStorageDirectory(),  is now deprecated.

Comment: Dont post links. Please post the used code now for saving your picture.

Comment: You use an Android 10 device? Further i do think that your question has nothing to do with CameraX. Where you first saved some bytes to a file in getExternalFilesDir() you now want to save those bytes to the MediaStore.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CameraX provides API for saving to MediaStore. Please take a look at the [ImageCapture#takePicture](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ImageCapture#takePicture(androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20androidx.camera.core.ImageCapture.OnImageSavedCallback)) API. Code sample:

```
val outputFileOptions = ImageCapture.OutputFileOptions.Builder(
    mContentResolver, 
    MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
    contentValues).build();
imageCapture.takePicture(outputFileOptions, ...
```